# Constructing objects using Variadic Templates and Tuples

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a means to construct/reinitialize a set of objects in a tuple using constructors whose arguments are passed as a tuple. My code should explain what I am trying to do it better. Unfortunately my code does not work. Testing the code using the following,

```
std::tuple<double, int>         in;
std::tuple<double, int>         arg(4., 5);
create<0>(in, arg);
```

I get the following error.

"error: no matching function for call to 'create'"
" note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction"

Can folks tell me what is going on? Here is the code.

```
     template<size_t k, typename ...R, typename ...T>
  static typename std::enable_if< k < sizeof...(R), void>::type create(std::tuple<R...> & v, std::tuple<T...> &in) {

    typename std::tuple_element<k, std::tuple<R...>>::type ans(std::get<k>(in));

    std::get<k>(v) = ans;
    create<k+1, R..., T...>(v, in);
}
```

Comment: The template parameter pack cannot be given here, and the recursion must be stopped. `if constexpr ( k + 1 < sizeof...(R) ) { create<k+1>(v, in); }`.

Comment: @dalfaB I am not sure I follow why. Your change worked and it compiled fine.

Comment: @dalfaB Is it that SFINAE does not work in this case? I was a bit surprised. Could you kindly elaborate what is going on there please. That would be very kind of you and very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
create<k+1, R..., T...>(v, in);
```

This is not valid because either the parameters are deduced or they are provided.
Here they are provided, so deduction is cut. The first call is then `create<1,double,int,double,int>( v, in )`.
The function receives its parameters but there are 5 non-discernible possibilities.

```cpp
create<1,double,int,double,int>   R=[], T=[double,int,double,int]
create<1,double,int,double,int>   R=[double], T=[int,double,int]
create<1,double,int,double,int>   R=[double,int], T=[double,int]
create<1,double,int,double,int>   R=[double,int,double, T=[int]
create<1,double,int,double,int>   R=[double,int,double,int], T=[]
```

Here the third case is the only one possible, but the deduction is deactivated!
If you do not indicate the parameters they are fairly deduced.

Then, it is imperative to stop the recursion.

The first call is `create<1>( v, in )` producing the instanciation for `k=1`

```cpp
    std::get<1>(v) = std::get<1>(in);
    create<2>(v, in);             // <== error function doesn't exist
```

But **because of the SFINAE**, the function create<2> does not exist. And it is an error to call an inexistant function

So a possible solution:

```cpp
template<size_t k, typename ...R, typename ...T>
  static typename std::enable_if< (k < sizeof...(R)), void>::type
  create( std::tuple<R...>& v, std::tuple<T...>const& in ) {

    std::get<k>(v) = std::get<k>(in);
    if constexpr ( k + 1 < sizeof...(R) ) {
        create<k+1>( v, in );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I get it awesome explanation. I did not really think about it in that detail. Since we stop recursion, we do not need SFINAE, I removed it.